# Error - Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:]

Tags: ios, swift

I have two collection views.  the first collection view without second collection view work fine. I don't know where is the problem in second collection view.

first collection view: `collection_options`
second collection view: `collection_contactus`

I got this error :

```
Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UICollectionView.m:4971
2017-03-07 21:43:14.188 kashanmap[32788:427373] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cellContentAJob - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

all of my class:

```
class ContentAJobViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var image_slider: ImageSlideshow!
    var job_id = "0"
    let db = DatabaseManager()
    var jobs = [GlobalHelper]()
    var job = GlobalHelper()


    @IBOutlet weak var label_title: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var collection_options: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var collection_contactus: UICollectionView!


    let reuseIdentifier             = "cellContentAJob"
    let reuseIdentifierContactUs    = "cell_content_a_job_contact_us"

    var item_options    = [String]()
    var item_contact_us = [GlobalHelper]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initialValues()
    }

    func initialValues()
    {
        db.openDatabase()

        collection_options!.dataSource = self
        collection_options!.delegate = self

        collection_contactus!.dataSource = self
        collection_contactus!.delegate = self


        self.image_slider.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        jobs = db.getContentAJob(id: job_id)
        job  = jobs[0]

        var arr_imgs = job.images.components(separatedBy: ",")
        var images = [InputSource]()
        for img in arr_imgs
        {
            let alamofireSource = AlamofireSource(urlString: img)!
            images.append(alamofireSource)
        }


        self.image_slider.setImageInputs(images)

        label_title.text = job.title

        self.image_slider.bringSubview(toFront:label_title)


        initialOptions()
        initialContactUs()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func initialOptions()
    {

        self.image_slider.bringSubview(toFront:collection_options)



        if(self.job.wifi == "1")
        {
            self.item_options.append("wififree")
        }

        if(self.job.apple_health == "1")
        {
            self.item_options.append("sib_noghrei")
        }
        if(self.job.wc == "1")
        {
            self.item_options.append("wc")
        }

        if(self.job.full_time == "1")
        {
            self.item_options.append("fulltime")

        }

        if(self.job.pos == "1")
        {
            self.item_options.append("pos")
        }

        if(self.job.parking == "1")
        {
            self.item_options.append("parking")
        }


        DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.collection_options.reloadData()

        }


    }

    func initialContactUs()
    {
        var phone       = GlobalHelper();
        var mobile      = GlobalHelper();
        var fax         = GlobalHelper();
        var web         = GlobalHelper();
        var email       = GlobalHelper();
        var hour_work   = GlobalHelper();
        var city        = GlobalHelper();
        var address     = GlobalHelper();
        var manager     = GlobalHelper();

        if(job.phone != "")
        {
            phone.images = "call_phone"
            phone.title = job.phone
            item_contact_us.append(phone)
        }


        if(job.mobile != "")
        {
            mobile.images = "call_mobile"
            mobile.title = job.mobile
            item_contact_us.append(phone)
        }

        if(job.fax != "")
        {
            fax.images = "fax"
            fax.title = job.mobile
            item_contact_us.append(fax)
        }

        if(job.website != "")
        {
            web.images = "network"
            web.title = job.website
            item_contact_us.append(web)
        }

        if(job.email != "email")
        {
            email.images = "email"
            email.title = job.email
            item_contact_us.append(email)
        }

        if(job.work_hours != "")
        {
            hour_work.images = "work_hours"
            hour_work.title = job.work_hours
            item_contact_us.append(hour_work)
        }

        if(job.city != "")
        {
            //city.images = ""
            address.title = job.city
            //item_contact_us.append(city)
        }

        if(job.address != "")
        {
            address.images = "address"
            address.title = job.address
            item_contact_us.append(address)
        }

        if(job.manager != "")
        {
            manager.images = "manager"
            manager.title = job.manager
            item_contact_us.append(manager)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.collection_contactus.reloadData()

        }


    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */







    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

    // tell the collection view how many cells to make
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if(collectionView == collection_options)
        {
           return self.item_options.count
        }

        if(collectionView == collection_contactus)
        {
            return self.item_contact_us.count
        }

        return 0;

    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellContentAJobCollectionViewCell

        if(collectionView == collection_options)
        {
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellContentAJobCollectionViewCell


            let image_name = self.item_options[indexPath.row]
            cell.img_view_cell_options.image = UIImage(named: image_name as! String)

            return cell
        }

        if(collectionView == collection_contactus)
        {

            let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierContactUs, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellContactUsCollectionViewCell

            let image_name = self.item_contact_us[indexPath.row].images
            cell1.img_view_cell_contact_us.image = UIImage(named: image_name as! String)
            cell1.label_view_cell_contact_us.text = self.item_contact_us[indexPath.row].title

            return cell1
        }

        return cell;



    }
}
```

---

**updated**

[image]

---

**updated**

I found the problem,
when I comment `item_contact_us.append(obj)` 's everything work fine !

why?

Comment: How are you giving your cell identifier?

Comment: Have you given your cell identifier in storyboard ?? Or if your using nib have you registered your cell ?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: Error is on cellContentAjob have you given that as well?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: WHY APPENDING PHONE HERE INSTEAD OF MOBILE??-: if(job.mobile != "")
        {
            mobile.images = "call_mobile"
            mobile.title = job.mobile
            item_contact_us.append(phone)
        }

Comment: I comment all append's but first. but I got the same error.

Comment: `var item_contact_us = [GlobalHelper]()`

Comment: why don't you create a model class and append your data in array as an object in form of key value pair??